# output the value of precedin-sibling if the sibling satisfies a condition

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to output the value of ID (5018) if the ID_Type = 'BadgeId'

xml code:

```
<ws:Identification_Data>
    <ws:ID>14007</ws:ID>
    <ws:ID_Type>ID1</ws:ID_Type>
</ws:Identification_Data>
<ws:Identification_Data>
    <ws:ID>5018</ws:ID>
    <ws:ID_Type>BadgeId</ws:ID_Type>
</ws:Identification_Data>
```

xslt:

```
 <Badge_Number>
   <xsl:value-of select="ws:Identification_Data[ws:ID_Type='BadgeId']/preceding-                                           sibling::ws:ID/text()"/>
 </Badge_Number>
```

Comment: <ws:Identification_Data>
  <ws:ID>14007</ws:ID>
  <ws:ID_Type>ID1</ws:ID_Type>
</ws:Identification_Data>
<ws:Identification_Data>
  <ws:ID>5018</ws:ID>
  <ws:ID_Type>BadgeId</ws:ID_Type>
</ws:Identification_Data>

Comment: xslt:           <Badge_Number>
  <xsl:value-of select="ws:Identification_Data[ws:ID_Type='BadgeId']/preceding-sibling::ws:ID/text()"/>
</Badge_Number>

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not quite clear, because (a) you show us only a part of your XML and - even more importantly - (b) you don't tell us where you are when you need this.

Assuming your context is the parent node of the `<ws:Identification_Data>` nodes, you could call:

```
<Badge_Number>
    <xsl:value-of select="ws:Identification_Data[ws:ID_Type='BadgeId']/ws:ID"/>
</Badge_Number>
```

and get:

```
<Badge_Number>5018</Badge_Number>
```

as the result in your example. There is no need here to look for the preceding sibling; you select the parent that has the correct Type child, and from there select its other (ID) child.